# Removed /run/resolvconf

Tags: internet, dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I accidentally removed /run/resolvconf/ and can't install it using apt-get because I get a fetch error. Is there any way to get it back? I am not too knowledgeable of this so I am aware that I am missing some other details that may be needed to further assess the problem. However, I don't know what they are. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There are no file in Ubuntu called `/resolvconf/resolv.conf` .. are you thinking of `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: that file is there but when I try to open it, I get an error. It says that the file is broken because its target file does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, I typed this up without my computer in front of me. I will fix all mistakes as soon as I have access to it again.

Comment: I concur with the first comment, there's no such file.

Comment: Perhaps you removed the *symbolic link* to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Hi, after checking, I realized I actually deleted the entire /run/resolvconf directory

Comment: Run `sudo resolvconf -u` and see if it is recreated.

Comment: says "sudo: resolvconf: command not found"

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: @muru This is 16.04

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the title. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/15003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed!

On another computer, I downloaded this [resolvconf package](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/264128024/resolvconf_1.79ubuntu1_all.deb), copied it onto a USB and then from the USB to my broken machine. Then I installed those packages using: `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`. Then I used `sudo resolvconf -u` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.

I do not know what the commands `sudo resolvconf -u` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` do, but they worked for me!

If anyone cares to explain, I am eager to hear.